# Test not recognising default property `form.invalid` in a template driven form

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I would like to test a template driven form. Initially I would like the form's button to be disabled since I want to make sure the user enters a name. This is done by the 'required' property on the name input field.

So I created the following template:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <!-- note the 'required' property on the input field -->
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    #name="ngModel"
    required
    ngModel
  />
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>
  {{ form.invalid | json }}
</form>
```

This renders nicely in the browser:

[image]

Now I would like to test this behavior. And here is where it gets funky. The test is as follows:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

describe("AppComponent", () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let el: DebugElement;
  let button: HTMLButtonElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    el = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    button = el.query(By.css("button")).nativeElement;
  });
  describe("submit button", () => {
    it("should be disabled by default", () => {
      expect(button.nativeNode.disabled).toBeTrue();
    });
  });
});
```

My test fails and it does not recognise the `form.invalid` property. It sets it to 'false':

[image]

So my best guess would be that the actual 'ng build' or 'ng serve' of the Angular application does some magic that sets the ngForm to have an invalid property if one of the input values does not match the requirements.

But how do I do this in my test?

I would like the test to be as close to the real world example. So having to set `form.invalid` to `true` manually kinda defeats the purpose of the test.

Here's a Stackblitz example of the forementioned code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pfnkfc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that there are some asynchronous tasks that need to complete (we await `fixture.whenStable` and then we need to call `fixture.detectChanges()`. This is one of the reasons why I use reactive forms almost always because it is much easier to test. You can test them just by the TypeScript code alone and you don't have to look at the HTML at all.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let el: DebugElement;
  let button: HTMLButtonElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    el = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('submit button', () => {
    it('should be disabled by default', async () => {
      await fixture.whenStable(); // wait for all asynchronous tasks to complete
      fixture.detectChanges(); // call detectChanges again
      button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
      expect(button.disabled).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Things to note:

1.) Every time you call `fixture.detectChanges`, you need a new reference to `fixture.debugElement.query...` because the view changes every time you call `fixture.detectChanges`. If we were to keep using `el` like you have in the `beforeEach`, you would have an old reference to how the HTML looked like.

2.) You don't need to import `CommonModule` in Angular unit tests.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for the clear explanation and notes.